# laravel undefined offset 0

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I got an error

**Undefined offset: 0 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\office\ccodez\resources\views\services\service-details.blade.php)**

My Services, about page and contact page is also show same errors.

Routes/web.php
[image]

services.blade.php
[image]

services.service-details.blade.php
[image]

ServiceController.php
[image]

IndexController.php
[image]

Please give me a solution i tried so hard but can't able to fix

Comment: remove index `{{ $services->s_tagline }}` in services.service-details.blade.php

Comment: Please do not us images, there is a button to style code.

Comment: slug unique in service? @mustufa

Comment: {{ $services->s_tagline }} is use it but this time its show NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index Controller

```
public function show($slug) {
    $service = Service::where('s_slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('')->with(compact('service'));
}
```

in Service Blade

```
<h2 class="font-size-25">{{ $service->s_name}}  </h2>
```

Comment: I was tried it but it not working.

Comment: whats error occurs now?

Comment: this method Route::get('/slug',''); put after service/slug route

Comment: Thanks a Lot Ankita Patel. My code is working. But please explain the logic. to place route after service route. please explain.

Comment: @MUSTUFA  /{slug} this type of url is dynamic url ,never make this type of url,any text enter after main-url this url is called.and if make then put at the end of all routes.